How can I create a procedurally stained wall material?
For the material, I would like to create the concrete material and the stains that seem to be caused by water leaks. Particularly, I'd like to know how to create the stain patches for the material.


You can make it more complicated but maybe to begin mix some stretched Noise Texture nodes with a gradient on Z through some Color Mix nodes:

